# Convert API endpoint data into Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, string, axios

```
{
    "url": "{\n    \"StackId\": \"bla..bla..balaa\"\n}\n\" http://blaa..blaaa.com \"\n"
}
```

Hello Friends,
I am trying to build a table from above data from **API endpoint**.
Above is the data I am receiving as response using **React AXIOS**.

Please help me with a solution or reference to follow.
I want that above response like a **array** to use **UI Material Table**

I want id separately and url separately as a array.

Thanks in advance

Required output:

```
{
"id" = StackId:bla..bla..balaa
"url" = http://blaa..blaaa.com 
}
```

Comment: that data is unreadable ... how can url be separate from stackid, since stackid is a property of url? ... and how can that be converted to an array? given that data, what do you expect will be the resulting array? In other words, what do you want as an output given that input? I'm having trouble figuring out the format of that data, it's not quite JSON

Comment: Hi Jaromanda updated the post with required output

Comment: Are the values of the output object strings? eg. `{ id: "StackId:bla..bla..balaa", url: "http://blaa..blaaa.com" }`

Comment: Please post the *API endpoint code* as we can suggest a way to serialize the data suitable for you're need. Usually you didn't send raw data and clean them on the client, you serve the client well shaped data.

Comment: OK, so can you show a little more about the format of the data coming from the API - it looks ... odd ... also, you speak of an Array, so far there's nothing suggesting an Array